# Need to run sikuli script on remote PC using PsExec

Tags: psexec, sikuli-script

I have maintained a sikuli script which runs good for a GUI application on my PC, say PC-A. Also I have PsExec installed on it. My GUI application is installed on PC-B.
What I need to do is, run the sikuli script (on PC-A) to execute for GUI app on (PC-B) using PsExec as mediator, which should pass on my commands at every single line and return the results back to PC-A from GUI application.

SikuliX Script(PC-A) ====== PsExec.exe(PC-A) ======= GUI App(PC-B)

Regards,
Bharath

Answer (score 0):

To run interactively in a specific session of a remote PC you'll need to know the session id on the remote system.

You can then use `psexec`'s `-i` option to run in that session. From `psexec -?`

> -i Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the
>             specified session on the remote system. If no session is
>             specified the process runs in the console session.